# Erro ao atribuir um malloc a um inteiro em linguagem C

Tags: c, malloc, biginteger

Olá

Eu estou seguindo um tutorial no Youtube sobre alocação de memória dinâmica em linguagem c, mas eu estou obtendo um erro em relação a atribuição de um malloc() a uma variável do tipo inteiro. O estranho é que no tutorial não dá este erro, porque somente eu estou obtendo este erro ?

O erro está nesta linha:

```
numeros = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Erro:

```
malloc.cpp: In function 'int main()':
malloc.cpp:39:20: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [- 
fpermissive]
numeros = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
          ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Meu código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
// Variáveis de teste de ponteiros
int *numeros;
int n;

printf("Quantidade de numeros:");
scanf("%d",&n);

numeros = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Numero %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d",&numeros[i]);
}

printf("Numeros lidos: ");
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%d", numeros[i]);
}
printf("\n");

return 0;

}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Qual erro seu compilador está acusando? (Se puder editar e incluir na pergunta, ajudaria bastante)

Comment: Pronto, Editado.

Comment: Ah sim. Isso depende do compilador que você está usando. Existe algum motivo para você salvar seu arquivo com final ```.cpp```? Deveria ser apenas ```.c```.  ```.cpp``` é para  C++. De qualquer forma, experimente colocar um typecast na frente: ```numeros = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));```

Comment: Obrigado. eu vou testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
malloc.cpp: In function 'int main()':
malloc.cpp:39:20: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [- 
fpermissive]
numeros = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

O erro pode ser do tutorial ou seu: depende de quem chamou o arquivo de malloc.**cpp**.

Essa extensão é assumida para programas em C++. Em C++ `malloc()` pode ser usada, mas `new` seria o substituto normal.

Use `.c` para seus programas em C. Há uma opção do compilador também --- pesquise na documentação -- para definir qual a linguagem e poder usar qualquer extensão.

Em C++ essas conversões implícitas são proibidas, partindo da idéia de que qualquer conversão implícita é um certo risco. C++ não aceita. Mas o compilador C++ compila C e aí está o (seu) problema.

`malloc()` retorna `void*`. Você declarou `numeros` como `int*` e assim tem implícita uma conversão, exatamente o que o compilador está dizendo.

Declare

```
    int*    numero = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Prefira o singular, já que vai acabar escrevendo `numero[i]` por exemplo :) e é melhor de ler que `numeros[i]`. E declare `int*` `coisa` e não `int    *coisa`, porque está declarando `coisa` afinal. E é o que o compilador vai dizer: qual o tipo de `coisa`? `int*`. Você declara um nome.

Comment: Obrigado. eu vou testar.